# Why can't I install a new nuget package manually?

Tags: .net, nuget

This should be simple, but I cannot figure it out. I cannot install my nuget package manually.

I created an empty .Net standard project with Class1.cs and built, and packed it.

[image]

Then I created another console application and try to install the package manually, but it cannot find it.

> **Unable to find package 'NugetTest'**

[image]

I tried to update the project file with the package id, but that doesn't help:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
        <PackageId>NugetTest</PackageId>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

But when I pack again, and install again, I get the same error.

If I rename the nupkg file to a Zip file, it also seems fine:

[image]

The .nuspec file in the Zip also seem fine to me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>NugetTest</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>NugetTest</authors>
    <owners>NugetTest</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package Description</description>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Comment: Try to add your source for NuGet in VS: go to Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Source. And add path to Dubug folder of your NuGet.

Comment: Unfortunately not, it didn't work. Same error 'Install-Package : Unable to find package 'NugetTest'